# <chatter:follow> in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, chatter, custom, follow

In a VisualForce page we can use `<chatter:follow>` to show a Follow/Unfollow button on a page:

```
<chatter:follow rendered="true" entityId="..." />
```

What is the equivalent for a custom lightning component? IE: How can we show a Follow/Unfollow button in a custom lightning component for a given record? When trying the above in a custom lightning component we get the error:

```
No COMPONENT named markup://chatter:follow found
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no OOTB `chatter:follow` component in lightning, however, you can refer to the [Lightning Components Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_forceChatter_feed.htm) on using

`forceChatter:feed` which

> Represents a Chatter Feed

and create a custom one to achieve this functionality